# Lookup formula that looks across multiple tabs in a single excel workbook

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to lookup the MIN value on one excel tab across several other excel tabs, all in the same workbook, and return the part # from yet another excel cell.

11/11/14 09:20
I have an excel workbook that I'm using to compile material pricing.  I've copied in three separate vendor "pricebooks" as tabs and created a fourth as a comparison tab.  The "pricebooks" have the following vendor specific details by columns:

A-Manufacturer part #(s)
B-Vendor substitution part #(s)
C-Item description
D-Manufacturer
E-Unit of Measurement
F-My price
G-List price

The comparison tab has the following columns:
A-Manufacturer part #(s)
B-Vendor substitution part #(s)
C-Item description
D-Manufacturer
E-Vendor 1's price 
F-Vendor 2's price
G-Vendor 3's price
H-Best Price =MIN(E2:G2)

What I need now is to be able to take the comparison tabs column H results and have it look up that price across the three vendor "pricebook" tabs and return results for column  B of the comparison tab.

Comment: You need to provide us more **specific** details.  Your question is far too vague for me to even begin to figure out how to approach it.

Comment: I just updated my question to include more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we know which vendor to use, we can do a vlookup to the vendor pricesheets to pull their part number.  The formula (for `B2`) for this is

```
=vlookup(A2, IF(H2=E2,pricebook1!$A:$B,IF(H2=F2,pricebook2!$A:$B,pricebook3!$A:$B)),2,0)
```